# @OneToOne or @ManyToOne error

Tags: java, jboss, entity, wildfly

I have created some entities but im having the below error when i run on server :

org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)

> [spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
>   [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
>   [spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]    ... 35 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne
>   on .....entities.exams.answer.questionId references an unknown entity:
>   .....entities.exams.question

here is the code of entities

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="..",name = "exam_answers")

@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "answer.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM answer s"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "answer.findByanswerId", query = "SELECT s FROM answer s WHERE s.answerId = :answerId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "answer.findByquestionId", query = "SELECT s FROM answer s WHERE s.questionId = :questionId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "answer.findByanswer", query = "SELECT s FROM answer s WHERE s.answer = :answer") })
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL, region = "exams")
public class answer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = Generationquestion.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "answer_id")
    private Integer answerId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private question questionId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "exam_id", referencedColumnName = "exam_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private exam examId;
    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "answer")
    private String answer;

    public answer() {
    }

    public answer(Integer answerId) {
        this.answerId = answerId;
    }

...SETTERS AND GETTERS... 
}


@Entity
@Table(schema="..",name = "question")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "question.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM question s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "question.findByquestionId", query = "SELECT s FROM question s WHERE s.questionId = :questionId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "question.findByLabel", query = "SELECT s FROM question s WHERE s.label = :label"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "question.findByquestion", query = "SELECT s FROM question s WHERE s.question = :question"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "question.findByInputquestion", query = "SELECT s FROM question s WHERE s.inputquestion = :inputquestion"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "question.findByOptions", query = "SELECT s FROM question s WHERE s.options = :options")})
public class question implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = Generationquestion.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    private Integer questionId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 500)
    @Column(name = "label")
    private String label;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    @Column(name = "question")
    private String question;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "input_question")
    private String inputquestion;
    @Size(max = 500)
    @Column(name = "options")
    private String options;

    public question() {
    }

    public question(Integer questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }
```

Comment: You are not explaining which error message you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error cause

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on
.....entities.exams.answer.questionId references an unknown entity:     
.....entities.exams.question
```

Have you added `entities.exams.question` to the hibernate config?

A couple more points:

1. In java, classes should start with a capital letter. They should be called Question and Answer not question and answer
2. In your Answer class, the property shouldn't be called `questionId` as that's confusing. The word `id` should only ever be used for Long / Integer properties (and maybe String every now and then)

Comment: what is wrong with that ? I added a private question so i guess the query is correct @Lance Java